# Using is statement for strings

Tags: python, string

Can someone explain why I am getting following outputs? (I know this code has SyntaxWarning.)

```
>>> a = 'book'
>>> a is 'book'
True
```

```
>>> a = 'two book'
>>> a is 'two book'
False
```

I was expecting same result for both code snippet.

Comment: Try : `a in 'two book'`

Comment: why this code outputs True? :D

Comment: It has something to do with the internals of the Python runtime and might change between implementations and versions. Main point: Don't use `is` if you don't want to check for object identity.

Comment: Using `is` with literals subjects you to any number of implementation-specific details. Basically, you can't say with any certainty what object a literal will produce.

Comment: The `SyntaxWarning` is obliquely telling you that the comparison produces [unspecified behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing any 2 objects with "is" in python, you actually check the storage allocation of the 2 objects.

When creating a string, python tries to optimize the storage by using the same allocation for both. but this behavior isn't always consistent, for it might be different for other strings.

I notices this behavior changes when using a space (" ") as a part of the string.

Anyways, you should compare objects with "==" and not "is". This way, the comparison will use the "**eq**" method from the class of the object, as it should.
Or you may implement this method by yourself if you'd like to (using inheritance and overriding)